# I want to install Debian linux

Tags: debian

So I'm thinking of switching from Windows 10 to Debian linux. Now I have a 32 gb usb but Im not sure what to do now, because I'm scared of ruining my laptop so I want to be 100% sure how to do this. I have downloaded the Debian ISO and I want to ask you, what should I do now to cahnge my OS from Windows to Debian. Thank you in advance!

Comment: At the moment this question isn't very easy to answer. There are considerations such as, do you intend to dual boot with Windows, or are you happy to delete Windows altogether? Furthermore, there is a lot of documentation on the internet that already answers this question, and we're not running a "let me google that for you" service here ;) You would be better off linking to the documentation you intend to follow, and ask about the specific points that you find confusing.

Comment: For all I don't think this is a great question.  It's a very *well timed* question.  The instinct to stop, think, ask before doing something completely destructive is a very good instinct indeed.

Comment: learn how to remove and install a new hard drive or SSD in your laptop, if that is possible with your model laptop.  That way you take your Windows 10 drive out and there's no chance of messing it up.  New disks or SSD's are not expensive.

Answer (score 4):

If you're scared of this then this isn't the right time to switch.

There's several options that will let you use linux on your laptop without blowing away your windows 10 environment.  I'd suggest that instead of completely overwriting you pick one of the following options:

- Download and install [Oracle VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).  You can run linux as a virtual machine in a window inside MS windows. You can of course put the window into full screen mode.
- Turn your USB stick into a bootable linux pen drive.  Eg: using [PendriveLinux](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).  This basically uses the USB stick as a hard drive for linux, leaving windows completely untouched on your laptop hard drive.
- Follow the debian instructions for installing, but instead of overwriting windows, resize the windows partition and create a dual-boot system.  If you pick this option then find out how to install windows 10 from scratch if it all goes wrong!

Comment: An extra dotpoint might be to use the Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Comment: WSL is great for overall Linux environment learning and experimentation, but VirtualBox is definitely what I'd recommend as a nondestructive means to try "living" in a new OS.

Comment: WSL can potentially kill your entire Windows installation, especially if you're a newcomer to Linux, so use with caution.